# Is it possible to devise a physical experiment to calculate any irrational number?

Tags: experimental-physics

Suppose we for take example $\pi$ then one nice experiment to  find an approximate value for it is the [Buffon's Needle experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem). Suppose we are given any arbitary irrational number $\chi$, is it possible to find a physical experiment such that we can find a value of that number?

Comment: Depending on what it means to be "given" an irrational number, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223810/is-being-rational-decidable might be useful.

Comment: Limit of a seq  in R which is not rational Ig @ConnorBehan

Comment: Any analog computer?

Comment: Note that any number is an approximation in some sense to any other number.  The question is rather vague in that sense.

Comment: Indeed, $\pi$ is approximately 4.

Answer (score 0):

You use your seq. to  plot the number make a rectangle  the other side 1 and the needle Experiment. All  sqrt can be constructed physically, with rectangular triangles.  there are mechanical integrators, so you can approximate ln(x)  integrating 1/x. But also a computer is a physical instrument!

Answer (score 0):

Use an experiment that measures $1\mathrm{\ s}$. Convert that to units of “ticks” where $1\mathrm{\ s}=\chi\mathrm{\ ticks}$. Then you have a measurement of $\chi$.

Similar experiments can be done with any dimensionful measurement.